# How to check the barrier function is superharmonic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Suppose $n\geq 3$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. In the Perron's method to solve the PDE
\begin{equation}
-\Delta u = 0 \text{ in } \Omega \quad \text{and } u = g \text{ on }\partial\Omega,
\end{equation}
suppose the exterior sphere condition is satisfied: for every point $z\in\partial\Omega$, there exists a ball $B=B_R(y)$ satisfying $\overline{B}\cap\overline{\Omega}=\{z\}$. Then we can construct a barrier function $w$ given by:
\begin{equation}
w(x)=R^{2-n}-|x-y|^{2-n}.
\end{equation}
How can I show $w$ is a barrier function? Thank you.

$w$ is a barrier function if

1) $w$ is superharmonic in $\Omega$ $\quad$ and

2) $w > 0$ in $\overline{\Omega}-z$; $\quad$ $w(z)=0$.

The second condition is straightforward, but I don't know how to show the first condition.

$w$ is superharmonic in $\Omega$ if for every compact ball $B_1\subset\Omega$, and every harmonic function $h$ in $B_1$ satisfying $w \geq h$ on $\partial B_1$, we also have $w \geq h$ in $B_1$.

Comment: The second term is the negative of the fundamental solution to the Laplace equation (essentially). Since it has the minus sign, it is superharmonic. (The fundamental solution itself is subharmonic.) Then you add a constant to it and it retains this property.

Comment: Oh, I see. Does it mean I just take the Laplacian of $w$ and show that the result is $\geq 0$? Thank you.

Comment: You can't *exactly* do that, because the function isn't real-valued anymore at $x=y$, but that's the gist of it. More precisely, away from $x=y$ you can indeed take the Laplacian and you should find that it is *exactly* zero. Right at $x=y$ it is superharmonic in the sense that it lies below all of its spherical averages which are centered at $y$ (and this is trivial, because the local averages are finite while the function is $-\infty$ at $x=y$). This is usually what I've seen as the definition of superharmonic and subharmonic, but it is consistent with your definition too.

Comment: Also you have your inequality reversed: $\Delta u \leq 0$ for superharmonic functions. Though maybe you meant $-\Delta u \geq 0$ (the negative Laplacian is much more convenient...)

Comment: You are right. Actually, my definition for superharmonic is generalized in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book in section 2.8. I think $\Delta u \leq 0$ also implies the superharmonic in the book's sense. Is there any way we can show it using the book's definition? I'm thinking of Maximum Principle, but not sure.
Thanks again!

Comment: $\Delta u \leq 0$ implies superharmonicity, but there are superharmonic functions that are not even continuous. We've identified one, in fact!

Comment: I think I made an error: $1/|x|$ is harmonic on domains which don't include zero, and superharmonic on domains which do include zero. (I checked with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplacian+of+1%2F%28x^2%2By^2%2Bz^2%29^%281%2F2%29 . Note that the Dirac delta is positive as a distribution, so $\Delta(1/|x|) \leq 0$ in distributional sense.) So this problem is a bit less trivial than I thought, I think.